# Is it ok to use static properties to move data around the app?

Tags: java, android, variables, properties, static

I need to access a few of my custom objects in different activities of my application. For this purpose and for the sake of accessibility I have been using static properties for moving data from an activity to another.
For example I have the following class:

```
public class TrackItem {
    public String title, imageUrl, mediaUrl, type, artist, desc;
    public static TrackItem track;
}
```

And for starting an activity:

```
TrackItem.track = items.get(i); // 'items' is an arraylist defined elsewhere
Intent trackActivity = new Intent(c, TrackActivity.class);
startActivity(trackActivity);
```

And now inside the `TrackActivity` I can easily access `TrackItem.track` and use it's properties.
I just need to know if I'm making a mistake or not? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: A "singleton pattern" may be better, because it lets you control the access better--one reason to avoid `public static` variables is that they can be assigned at any time, anywhere in your app.  But I think you need one or the other, since there's no other good way to pass data between activities, other than small amounts in `Intent#putExtra`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The android way of dealing with that problem is to make your class

```
Parcelable
```

and pass it with the intent from one activity to another.

If you are initializing your static variables in an activity be aware of loosing data, because in android activity can be destroyed at any point after its state changed to pause. Moreover, your static variables can be erased if the entire application is killed by the system, that is happening rather frequently. Then you'll get the

```
NullPointerException
```

trying to access your data.

If you really want to use static members handle their initialization in the

```
Application
```

class constructor, so they will be recreated on the start of your application, being killed.

But in general it is not a good practice in android.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is OK in certain cases, but there might be other more suitable solutions.

You could have a central data store class that uses the singleton principle and therefore would be accessible from everywhere. You would add the item id to the `Intent` for the new `Activity`. Then, with the id, you could get the item from the data store.

You could also make the item serializable and just add it to the `Intent`.

One thing to keep in mind when using static members is that it could lead to a memory leak. Static members are related to the class and are therefore only garbage collected if you either set them to null, or the whole app gets killed and the classloader unloads this specific class.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is an unsafe practice because it is difficult to keep track of who is manipulating its data. It is much safer to use static variables for bookkeeping information, such as an ID which you can use to go look up the appropriate TrackItem (e.g. in an SQLite database), which is its own object and does not have the chance of something else editing it when it shouldn't be. It terms of OOP, using static variables as shared data breaks encapsulation.

If you are looking to send data around the app, it would be much better to do so either with intents, as others are saying, or with SharedPreferences. Both have the advantage that you are dealing with only one instance of the object at any given time, SharedPreferences have the added advantage of keeping the data around after the app has been killed, so that users can resume with the same track that was playing when they closed the app. And both of these are safer than using static members as shared data fields.